# STL container with generic/templated variables

Tags: c++, templates, generics, variables, stack

I would simply like to do something of the following:

```
template <typename T>
class gvar {
private:
    T var;
public:
    gvar(T var) : var(var) {}
};

std::stack<gvar> some_stack;
```

g++ spits out all kinds of errors about how gvar is not a type. Is this achievable in some relatively easy way? I prefer not to use boost::any / boost::variant.

edit:

To clarify on what I want:

An std::stack that can hold variables of different types (just primitives is fine).

Comment: Why not use boost::any? It is designed for exactly what you seem to be after (although your question is very vague, so it's hard to be sure) -- in any case, you never explain what it is you want the code to *do*. We can't guess from your made-up syntax how you'd like it to work. Do you want to be able to create a `std::stack` which can hold `gvar`s with multiple different types `T`? Like both `gvar<int>` and `gvar<float>` in the same stack?

Comment: @jalf: actually just 'int' and 'float' in the same stack would do... I was trying to do something with templates that I later figured not to work like that.

Comment: We'd like to know the reason that `union` doesn't meet your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want polymorphism, you'd use a base class:

```
class GVarBase
{
public:
  virtual ~GVarBase() {}
};

template <typename T>
class GVar: public GVarBase
{
public:
private:
  T mVar;
};

std::stack< std::unique_ptr<GVarBase> > stack;
```

Note that with the current code you have, even `std::stack< GVar<int> >` would not work, a default constructor is required.

Comment: With polymorphism, it'd be a *really* good idea to store pointers instead of objects. ;)

Comment: @jalf: didn't I ? */me is baffled*

Comment: Was that `unique_ptr` always there? I guess I should have paid more attention then. ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's what I was fishing for. Ended up making baseclass pure-virtual and overloading a couple of operators in my subclasses.

Answer (score 7):

Because `gvar` isn't a type, it's a type template. You need to specify a template argument for it:

```
std::stack< gvar<int> > some_stack;
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch by 2 seconds! ;)

Comment: that's the thing, I -dont- want to specify it. The type will only be known at runtime, and I just realized that templates dont work like that... any suggestions?

Comment: @Daniel: You could start by adding that information to your question. ;)

Comment: Templates have to get completely resolved at runtime. If you need types that will only be known at runtime it will depend on what you need to do, but you will probably need an abstract base class, and inherited implementations.

Answer (score 5):

You have to either instantiate the template class or approach this in some other way.  For example, you can make an `std::stack<gvar<int> >`, or you could try solutions such as [Boost::Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to specify what type to instantiate `gvar` over, something like:

```
std::stack<gvar<int> > some_stack;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can suffer with a limited span, that is you know full well the length of the collection you can look at using [tuples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).  Of course, you're also going to need to know the type in advance.

```
boost::tuple<gvar<double>,gvar<int>,gvar<double> > myItems;
```

Which in your case would probably be best expressed simply as:

```
boost::tuple<double,int,double> myItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  There's no way to do what you're trying to do.  More clarity on the problem you're trying to solve with this attempt might allow me to provide a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need something like this:

```
class gvar {
        struct base_val { 
                virtual ~base_val() {} 
        };
        template <class T>
        struct con_value : base_val{
                con_value(T val): value(val) {}
                T value; 
        };      
        base_val *var;
public:
        template <typename T>
        gvar(T var) : var(new con_value<T>(var)) {}
        template <typename T>
        T* getValue() { 
                con_value<T> *ptr = dynamic_cast<con_value<T>*>(var);
                if(ptr == NULL) return NULL;
                return &ptr->value;
        }
};

std::stack<gvar> some_stack;
```

(link to ideone with working example http://www.ideone.com/gVoLh)

This is simplified `boost::any`, so if you can, just use `boost::any` instead of this.

Comment: Little leaky, but instead of plain pointer one should use `boost:shared_ptr`. And if you use boost already you could use `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.